# How to remove horizontal scrollbar in dojo tree?

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

Can someone please suggest me how can I remove the horizontal scroll-bar appearing at the bottom of the dojo tree structure ?

I learnt there is a **.resize() function**  in dojo which can help but exactly I don't know how to implement this in my tree structure to remove the horizontal scroll-bar.Can someone suggest me.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tree container has a fixed width, you could just use CSS to adjust it. Otherwise, you could manually resize your container like this,

```
resize: function(d) {
    this.myContainer.resize(d);
}
```

If d is not of the proper size, you could use dojo getMarginBox(this.domNode) to get the size of your widget.

Comment: the issue is resolved. The optio you suggested will also work and we can do this by CSS disablement of the scrollbar for x and y coordinates.Thanks for answering